# Redefine theoremstyle

Tags: amsthm

(Admittedly a strange question). I have the following TeX files:

- `macros1.tex`
- `macros2.tex`
- `main.tex`

`main.tex` includes `macros1.tex` and `macros2.tex` in that order. I am not allowed to edit `macros1.tex` or `main.tex`. I can only edit `macros2.tex`.

`macros1.tex` defines various amsthm theorem environments that are used in `content.tex`. Some of these use `\theoremstyle{definition}`. I would like to change these to `\theoremstyle{plain}`. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: are you allowed to define other theorem environments?  if you are, then just invoke `\theoremstyle{plain}` and set up some more `\newtheorem` environments with names similar to those in the `macros1` file and use those instead.  there's no limit that i know of on how many times `\newtheorem` can be used

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I cannot, as I am not allowed to edit `main.tex`, which is where the theorem environments are invoked.

Comment: I can't understand why are you not allowed to define your own environments. You can do something like this `%%done by macro1.tex
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
%done by macro2.tex
\theoremstyle{plain}
\makeatletter
\let\thm\relax
\let\c@thm\relax
\makeatletter
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]`

Comment: Do you allowed *not* to load `macros1.tex`? By the way, it sounds really bizarre that you wouldn't be allowed to modify `main.tex`: Isn't that the file that contains the document you're writing?

Comment: you should be able to add `\newtheorem` statements in `macros2.tex`.  not all `\newtheorem` statements have to be grouped together in one place -- and in documents by other authors, they often aren't.

Comment: I agree that it's a weird setting. @MarcoDaniel, you can post as an answer, if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments it's not the best solution:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
%done by macro1.tex
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
%done by macro2.tex
\theoremstyle{plain}
\makeatletter
\let\thm\relax
\let\c@thm\relax
\makeatletter
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
\kant[1]
\end{thm}
 \end{document}
```